# Como remover um índice do localStorage

Tags: html, jquery, json, localstorage

Preciso fazer uma manipulação do `localStorage` e não to sabendo como remover um item de um índice. Sou bem iniciante no assunto e não to sabendo passar essa informação pro botão.

Segue o código:

```js
var base;
//verifica se tem alguma "KEY" no localStorage criada com o nome de 'base'
if (localStorage.getItem("base") != null) { // caso retorne nula
    //a base vai converter a String em parenteses para exibir como KEY mais pra frente
    base = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("base"));
} else {

    //caso ja esteja criada, declara a base como um vetor;
    base = {
        dados: []
    };
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btncadastrar").click(cadastrar);
    $("#btnlistar").click(listar);
    $("#btnlimpar").click(limpar);
    $(".excluir").click(function () {
        excluir();
        alert("test")
    });


});

function cadastrar() {

    if ($("#tarefa").val() != "") {
        //base de dados armazena em um array que é chamado pela base, que contem dados, e informa que o atributo recebido sera uma TAREFA:(variavel)
        base.dados.push({ tarefas: $("#tarefa").val() });
        //converte os valores por uma String JSON
        localStorage.setItem('base', JSON.stringify(base));
        $("#idlistar").val("");
        $("#tarefa").val("");
    } else {
        alert("Insira alguma tarefa")
    }
}


function listar() {
    $("#idlistar").empty();

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {

        base = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("base"));
        //inserindo em uma lista que inici no UL
        $("#idlistar").append(`<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="addlistaitem">`);
        for (var i = 0; i < base.dados.length; i++) {
            //dentro, vai inserir as linhas da lista de acordo com os dados puxados do localstorage
            //aqui no append eu também criei um botão, que formatei ele dentro do css pra deixar aquele botãozinho laranja
            //passar função d excluir quando clicar naquele botão tbm
            $("#idlistar").append(`<li class="border-1" class="list-group-item mb-2">${base.dados[i].tarefas}<input onClick="excluir()" type="button" class="excluir" value="x"></li>`)
        }
        //finaliza a ul(lista)
        $("#idlistar").append(`</ul>`);
    }
}


function excluir() {
    localStorage.setItem('base', JSON.stringify(base));
 
     for (var i = 0; i < base.dados.length; i++) {
         localStorage.removeItem(base.dados[i].tarefas);
     }
 
}

function limpar() {
    localStorage.clear();
    $("#idlistar").empty();
}
```

[image: Tela]

Comment: "remover um item de um índice" - como assim ? Quer remover um item de um array ? Não foi muito claro para o que essa afirmação significa.

Comment: Veja este link do [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clearing-localstorage-in-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

Com base na documentação já seria o suficiente, não?
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

localStorage.removeItem("base");

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/445951)